# Chernoff bound for Bernoulli random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)=1/2$ where $1\leq i\leq n, n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability

The Chernoff bound has a nice application for 0-1 valued Bernoulli random variables. But what about (-1)-1 valued Bernoulli random variables, especially when the expectation is 0? Do we only have Hoeffding's inequality for this case?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a Bernoulli variable with outputs $0$ and $1$, the transformed random variable $Y = 2X-1$ is a Bernoulli variable with outputs $-1$ and $1$, and you can use that to derive equivalent results.

Answer (score 1):

You've described a [Rademacher r.v.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) actually.
Chernoff and Hoeffding's say something about the decay of tail probability, and more generally, you can show that if your r.v. is subgaussian (tail probabilities decay at least as fast as Gaussian tails), it satisfies Chernoff and Hoeffding's. And bounded r.v.s are subgaussian, so Rademacher r.v.s satisfy the inequalities.